# How to quit test execution using cucumber hooks

Tags: java, spring, rest, cucumber, cucumber-java

i have gone through various post but couldn't find a easy solution to quit cucumber test execution if one of the my API Test fails. I want to use `@After` hook to quit the test execution if one of the condition fails. For example if my `result()` return `false` i don't want to execute remaining test. Is there a easy way such as

```
if(result() == false){ 
   cucumber.quit();
}
```

I am using rest assured with gradle for my API Automation.

Answer (score 3):

Updated the solution based on `M.P. Korstanje` comment.
You can skip tests by using `Assume`. The below is the one of the approach,

**Code**:

```
public class stepDef {
    static HashMap<String, String> conditions;
    static {
        conditions = new HashMap<String, String>();
    }
    
    @Before
    public void beforeTest(Scenario scenario) {
        if (conditions.containsKey("result") && conditions.get("result").equalsIgnoreCase("false")) {
            System.out.println("************************Test not executed.************************");
            Assume.assumeTrue(false);
        } else {
            System.out.println("************************Started************************");
        }
    }

    @After
    public void afterTest(Scenario scenario) {
        if (scenario.isFailed()) {
            conditions.put("result", "false");
        }
        System.out.println("************************Completed************************");
    }
}
```

**Output**:

```
@Test
Scenario Outline: Test scenario                                                                                            
************************Started************************
//Result
************************Completed************************

@Test
Scenario Outline: decision                            
************************Test not executed.************************
    org.junit.AssumptionViolatedException: got: <false>, expected: is <true>
    at org.junit.Assume.assumeThat(Assume.java:106)
    at org.junit.Assume.assumeTrue(Assume.java:50)
    at cucumberStep.stepDef.beforeTest(stepDef.java:69)
************************Completed************************
```

**Report**:

[image]

Comment: Cucumber also supports Assume and Assumptions. Use those instead of assert to make the scenario skip.